# Tests using NSubstitute fail when running in Mono pipeline

Tags: c#, mono, xunit, nsubstitute

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'NSubstitute.Core.SubstitutionContext' threw an exception.
      ---- System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      -------- System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      Stack Trace:
          at NSubstitute.Substitute.For (System.Type[] typesToProxy, System.Object[] constructorArguments) [0x00000] in <12c131832e33409abe0da20ca32c0932>:0 
          at NSubstitute.Substitute.For[T] (System.Object[] constructorArguments) [0x00000] in <12c131832e33409abe0da20ca32c0932>:0 
          at TriplogWebAPITest.Admin.AdminTripControllerTest..ctor () [0x0000c] in <77e0d73ea5c74efc8252fdf5f78920f3>:0 
          at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
          at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <2943701620b54f86b436d3ffad010412>:0
```

when running the unit tests on my local machine, everything is fine, the tests run and turn out positive.
but then i update my branch and the pipeline in gitlab has a go at it, then it fails. with the stacktrace stated above. Its not always this test, and it doesnt always fail, just very often.

i have tried to see if mono has an issue using NSubstitute and that turned out nothing, i also tried to find out if the console runner we use has any forum threads or known issues with NSubstitute and i havent found anything.

NSubsitute ver 4.2.1
Mono ver 5.14
xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.1

does anyone have any clue as to what the source of the problem is?
and what a potential solution could be?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry. The intermittency suggests threading (does it change if you force tests to run single threaded?). Here is the [SubstitutionContext initialiser](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/0daeb8586daecd0cc44a7acd85ec312d4fe2ce99/src/NSubstitute/Core/SubstitutionContext.cs#L19) and the [call it makes](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/0daeb8586daecd0cc44a7acd85ec312d4fe2ce99/src/NSubstitute/Core/DependencyInjection/NSubstituteDefaultFactory.cs#L18). Not sure if you can construct a minimal repro from there?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was `HttpContext.Current` that doesnt have good support for being set in Unit Tests, so a workaround was made in the class which is responsible for knowing about who the current user is in our system

```
public static class CurrentUser
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> _testItems;
        private static IPrincipal _testPrincipal;

        // Should only be used in tests
        public static void InitializeTestContext(List<Claim> claims, IPrincipal principal)
        {
            _testItems = claims.ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Value);
            _testPrincipal = principal;
        }
        public static bool IsOn => ((ClaimsPrincipal)(_testPrincipal ?? HttpContext.Current.User)).FindFirst("yes") != null;

        public static bool IsTrue(string text) => _testPrincipal?.IsTrue(text) ?? HttpContext.Current.User.IsTrue(text);

        public static ClaimsPrincipal GetClaimsPrincipal() => (ClaimsPrincipal) (_testPrincipal ?? HttpContext.Current.User);
        private static string GetString(string prop) => _testItems != null ? _testItems[prop] : (string) HttpContext.Current.Items[prop];
   }
```